# Do Messianic Jews accept the entire New Testament?

Tags: canon, messianic-judaism

Do Messianic Jews accept the entire New Testament as a base of their belief?
What is the position of Messianic Judaism (if there is a common position) on passages in the Gospel of John and the letters of Paul that can be understood as that Jesus was a form of God?

---

Addition, as asked to say more about what are the passages that can be understood as that Jesus was a form of God.

John 1:1

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
> was God.

John 1:14

> And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, full of grace and truth;
> we have beheld his glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father.

Stating «the Word was God» and «the Word became flesh» he sets the base for the thought that God, the Holy Spirit and Jesus *are the same*, which is not the Jewish (and Muslim) concept of God.

Numbers 23:19

> God is not man, that he should lie, or a son of man, that he should
> repent. Has he said, and will he not do it? Or has he spoken, and will
> he not fulfil it?

Hosea 11:9

> I will not execute my fierce anger, I will not again destroy E'phraim;
> for I am God and not man, the Holy One in your midst, and I will not
> come to destroy.

Comment: I would urge visiting a well known Messianic Jewish scholar who has his own youtube channel and regularly debates on a range of topics...including his "pro trinitarianism" belief. https://www.youtube.com/user/AskDrBrownVideos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Do Messianic Jews accept the entire New Testament as a base of their belief?  Yes.***

> The Holy Bible is the main religious text for Messianic Jews. They follow the teachings of the Torah (Old Testament) while also holding the New Covenant (New Testament) as God’s Truth. They believe Old Testament prophesies about the coming Messiah were fulfilled in the New Testament with the birth, death, and resurrection of Jesus Christ.

> 1. Bible - Messianic Jews believe the Bible is God’s Holy Word and follow the Old and New Testament. The Old Testament serves as a history of the Jewish nation, God’s covenant with Abraham, and the commandments given to Moses. The New Testament fulfills the Old Testament through the coming of Jesus Christ, the Promised Messiah and God’s Son.

> 2. Jesus Christ - Messianic Jews believe that Jesus Christ is the Promised Messiah prophesied in the Old Testament. He is referred to in Hebrew as Yeshua and regarded as the way of salvation for all who believe in his death and resurrection. They believe that Jesus’ death was payment for the sins of all. (Acts 2)

> 3. Trinity - Most Messianic Jews believe in the Trinity as God in three parts. God the Father, God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit are all displayed in the New Testament Scriptures through the Gospels (the first four books) and the book of Acts.

> 4. Sin - Messianic Jews acknowledge that sin is any behavior that is against the teachings of the Bible. Sin can only be forgiven through faith in the death and resurrection of Jesus Christ. (2 Corinthians 5)

Source: https://www.christianity.com/church/denominations/what-do-messianic-jews-believe-and-practice.html

***Most, but not all, Messianic Jews accept the orthodox view of the Trinity.***  God the Father, God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit as three representations of the same divinity.

> God the Father: Messianic Jews believe in God, and that he is all-powerful, omnipresent, eternally existent outside of creation, and infinitely significant and benevolent. Some Messianic Jews affirm both the Shema and the Trinity, understanding the phrase "the LORD is One" to be referring to "a differentiated but singular deity" and "eternally existent in plural oneness".

> God the Son: Most Messianic Jews consider Jesus to be the Messiah and divine as God the Son, in line with mainstream Christianity, and will even pray directly to him. Many also consider Jesus to be their "chief teacher and rabbi" whose life should be copied.

> God the Holy Spirit: According to some Messianic Jews, the Spirit is introduced in the Old Testament, is the inspirer of prophets, and is the spirit of Truth described in the New Testament.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messianic_Judaism#The_Trinity

You say: “Stating «the Word was God» and «the Word became flesh» he sets the base for the thought that God, the Holy Spirit and Jesus are the same, which is not the Jewish (and Muslim) concept of God.”

Please be aware that the the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit are not “the same”.  That is not the Trinitarian concept.  Trinitarians acknowledge that there is only the One Being of God within whom subsist the three personages of Father, Son and Holy Spirit.  Each is co-eternal and co-equal but they are DISTINCT, one from the other.  Source: Athanasian Creed.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but why are they 'Messianic Jews' and not just 'Christians'?

Comment: Just did a bit of surface level googling, apparently Israel considers them Christians and not Jews, but they call themselves Jews and not Christians. Very interesting.

Comment: This answer is correct as far as it goes, but it ignores the important issue of the NT's attitude toward the Jewish Law.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the NT and Christology, I agree with @Lesley that "Most, but not all, Messianic Jews accept the orthodox view of the Trinity." However, the issue does not stop there, for Messianic Jews still need to decide how the OT, the Torah laws and the teaching of the rabbis apply to them in light of their acceptance of Jesus.

### Halakha and the "Old" covenant

[Halakha](https://ourrabbis.org/main/halakhah-mainmenu-26/halakhic-introduction) refers to the Law of the Torah and its interpretation. While Messianic Jews generally agree with Paul's teaching that salvation does not come from "works of the Law," many also believe that the original covenant between God and the Jewish people is still very much alive. Some therefore also believe that they should uphold the OT Law as best they can. They strongly reject the idea held by many Christians (based on Hebrews 8:13) that the "old" covenant is obsolete.

This opens a large number of questions, from [Sabbath-keeping](https://ourrabbis.org/main/halakhah-mainmenu-26/community-practices/practices-shabbat) to [observing Jewish Holidays](https://ourrabbis.org/main/halakhah-mainmenu-26/community-practices/holidays-mainmenu-33), the Torah's rules on ritual purity, [prayer](https://ourrabbis.org/main/halakhah-mainmenu-26/community-practices/prayer-mainmenu-36), circumcision, and many others. (Note that the links above represent [one major group of Messianic Jews](https://ourrabbis.org/main/). Other groups and individuals will have different views.)

To take one specific example, consider the issue of hand-washing. Confronted by the Pharisees on this *halakhic* controversy, Jesus declared:

> It is not what enters one’s mouth that defiles that person; but what
> comes out of the mouth is what defiles one. (Matthew 15:11)

Messianic Jews will agree with this statement and would not condemn someone for failing to wash their hands in circumstances such as those described in Mt. 15. On the other hand, many would indeed follow the rabbinical teaching that Jews should wash their hands before eating whenever possible and would recite the [traditional prayer for this](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/hand-washing/).

Turning to the specific halakhic issue of *kashrut*:

### Dietary laws

To understand Messianic Jewish attitudes on the [NT's teaching on dietary laws](https://tzion.org/articles/Kosher.html), we should consider the following two NT scriptures:

Acts 10

> He (Peter) saw heaven opened and something resembling a large sheet
> coming down, lowered to the ground by its four corners. 12 In it were
> all the earth’s four-legged animals and reptiles and the birds of the
> sky. 13 A voice said to him, “Get up, Peter. Slaughter and eat.” 14
> But Peter said, “Certainly not, sir. For never have I eaten anything
> profane and unclean.” 15 The voice spoke to him again, a second time,
> “What God has made clean, you are not to call profane.”

Acts 15:19

> We ought to stop troubling the Gentiles who turn to God, 20 but tell
> them by letter to avoid pollution from idols, unlawful marriage, the
> meat of strangled animals, and blood.

For Messianic Jews the question arises as to whether they consider themselves bound by God's admonition to Peter, by the policy of Acts 15:19, or by the various dietary laws found in the Torah and the teachings of the rabbis.

On this issue, Messianic Jews have basically three attitudes: a) Some follow rabbinical kosher laws, 2) some follow Torah kosher laws (but not rabbinical interpretations of them) and 3) some follow no dietary laws, just as other Christians. Among this latter group there may also be some that follow Acts 15:19 and are therefore careful to make sure meat is properly butchered and completely cooked. Presumably they would also avoid food served in Buddhist, Hindu or other "pagan" festivals.

**Answer**: Most Messianic Jews accept the entire New Testament but, just as other Christians do, they have many interpretations of it. Most reject implications drawn from the NT that the "old" covenant is obsolete.  Also, they are divided on the question of whether they still need to follow the Law of the Torah and rabbinical interpretations of it.